# Evaluate condition irrespective of first outcome

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know this is probably a newbie question, however I need to get a recommendation for the design of this.

I need to evaluate the result of a set of conditions and they must be evaluated irrespective of the outcome of a preceding condition. This brings the case of using regular OR(|) or short-circuit evaluation using ||.

Below is the code that I need to make a design decision about, however the end goal is to be able to evaluate or condition regardless.

```
private bool checkExistingBPNInSession()
{
    var exDirectors = (List<ViewModels.NewContact>)Session["NewDirectorDetails"];
    var exTaxConsultant=(List<ViewModels.NewContact>)Session[Resources.Global.NewTaxConsultantDetails];
    var exTaRep = (List<ViewModels.NewContact>)Session["NewTaxRepresentativeDetails"];
    if (exDirectors.Count() != 0 || exTaRep.Count() != 0 || exTaxConsultant.Count() != 0)
    {
        var QueryCheckDir = (from x in exDirectors where x.BPN==txtBusinessPartnerIdNumber.Text select x.BPN).ToList();
        var QueryCheckTaxConsultant = (from x in exTaxConsultant where x.BPN == txtBusinessPartnerIdNumber.Text select x.BPN).ToList();
        var QueryCheckTaxRep = (from x in exTaRep where x.BPN == txtBusinessPartnerIdNumber.Text select x.BPN).ToList();
        if (QueryCheckDir.Count() > 0 || QueryCheckTaxConsultant.Count() > 0 || QueryCheckTaxRep.Count() > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

These parts here have to be evaluated:

`exDirectors.Count() != 0 || exTaRep.Count() != 0 || exTaxConsultant.Count() != 0` 
and this also

```
QueryCheckDir.Count() > 0 || QueryCheckTaxConsultant.Count() > 0 || QueryCheckTaxRep.Count() > 0
```

Please, I am seeking the best recommendations.

Thanks guys.

Comment: If you don't care whether the first condition is true or not then why evaluate it?

Comment: Hello Ben, I definitely do care about the first condition be evaluated, however, if its evaluate to false, I need to evaluation to proceed to the next condition...hope I am clear. thanks

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you mean, `if(X || Y)` will evaluate Y if X is false, it will not evaluate Y if X is true.

Comment: Don't use `Enumerable.Count`(which executes the complete query in case of a lazy sequence just to detect the count) but `Enumerable.Any`. Here is doesn't matter since `List.Count` will be used, but next time you'll use it also on a query like `from row in db.LargeTable`. `Any` does also express the intention more clearly.

Comment: @BenRobinson however, because of the way I need the logic to run, it has to evaluate Y even if X is true

Comment: If you want it to alwyas evaluate both you can use | instead, but the outcome of the if will be identical so could you explain in more detail why you think this is needed?

Comment: Thanks Ben for the response, I have different "buckets" of query session object to test to see if a value exist. Now if that value doesn't exist in a one "bucket" for a intent it might exist in another bucket. Therefore, I need a maintainable way of checking the value in one if logic...Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

If you want an evaluation done, no matter what, you should use the

[`|-operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx) - this will evaluate every condition even if the outcome of the final expression would not change *(contrary to [`||-operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx))*

Here is a [simple demo using dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XLKKWd)

Comment: that is subjective (imho) and a whole other question, but from a certain point of view I tend to think it is not. Most people will be under the impression if a condition will be false no matter the following conditions that those will then not be evaluated, but as I said: subjective ;)